# Responsive buttons in css

Tags: css, button, responsive

I know that here is many answers about responsive buttons, but I didn't found any solution to solve my problem.

I hope you may help me!

Here I have 3 buttons. Help me please to make it responsive.

```
.btn{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:10px!important;padding:10px!important;font-size:14px;clear:both;display:inline-block;text-decoration:none!important;color:#FFF!important;}
.btn ul {margin:0;padding:0}
.btn li{display:inline;margin:30px;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.icosite,.whitepaperlink,.watchyt{padding:12px 15px!important;color:#fff!important;font-weight:700;font-size:14px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;opacity:.95;border:0;transition:all .2s ease-out}
.icosite {background-color:#6829b7; -moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;}
.whitepaperlink {background-color:#606060; -moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;}
.icosite:hover {background-color:#29b765;color:#fff; opacity:1; -moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;}
.whitepaperlink:hover {background-color:#29b765;color:#fff; opacity:1; -moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;}
.icosite:before {content:&#39;\f064&#39;;font-size: 1.5em;display:inline-block;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;margin-right:10px;width:16px;height:16px;line-height:18px;font-family:fontawesome;transition:all 0.5s ease-out;}
.whitepaperlink:before {content:&#39;\f1c1&#39;;font-size: 1.5em;display:inline-block;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;margin-right:10px;width:16px;height:16px;line-height:18px;font-family:fontawesome;transition:all 0.5s ease-out;}
.watchyt,.whitepaperlink,.icosite{padding:12px 15px!important;color:#fff!important;font-weight:700;font-size:14px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;opacity:.95;border:0;transition:all .2s ease-out}
.watchyt {background-color:#ff0000; -moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;}
.watchyt:hover {background-color:#29b765;color:#fff; opacity:1; -moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;}
.watchyt:before {content:&#39;\f16a&#39;;font-size: 1.5em;display:inline-block;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;margin-right:10px;width:16px;height:16px;line-height:18px;font-family:fontawesome;transition:all 0.5s ease-out;}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 3 buttons what ? what is your html like? what do you want to achieve with responsive ? should they all be under each other in responsive ? show us something pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Sorry for the small number of details) They all should be one by one in a row. But if this doesn't change the display on large screens, they all may be be under each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say a responsive button I assume you're asking a button that looks good on mobile and desktop. In this case, you would use media queries to resize the button based on the type of device you're using. I also don't recommend you use !important at all ex)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! Thank you for your fast answer. But I really don't understand in which place in my code I must add your code.

Comment: Yes of course. Media Queries is a feature of CSS. You can add it anywhere in your CSS file like you would any other element. Personally, I put it at the end. So you create your regular p element with a font-size of 20px. Then in the media query, you put 16px when the max-width is 768px. You can also put more than one element in the media query like an h1 and a p

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you mean. But the fact is that the template is responsive, and problem is just in this new buttons, which don't resize on mobile devices. I think I need to add something exactly in this css code.

Comment: You should be able to resize buttons with media queries. Make sure you state rules for both for ex) padding: 16px 32px 16px 32px; in normal CSS and in the media queries padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;

Comment: Aha! I understood!

Comment: Perfect! Make sure to mark this as done and my answer as correct if you're satisfied

Comment: Thank you very much Danny!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which I was added!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    .btnpost,.icosite,.whitepaperlink,.watchyt {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
margin: auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;

    }


}
```